# MongoDB : Can't insert twice the same document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

On my pymongo code, inserting twice the same doc raises an error :

```
document = {"auteur" : "romain",
            "text" : "premier post",
            "tag" : "test2",
            "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
collection.insert_one(document)
collection.insert_one(document)
```

raises :

```
DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.myCollection index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5aa282eff1dba231beada9e3') }
```

inserting two documents with different content works fine.

Seems like according to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options I should do something aobut option of indexes:

```
unique  boolean 
Optional. Creates a unique index so that the collection will not accept insertion or update of documents where the index key value matches an existing value in the index.

Specify true to create a unique index. The default value is false.

The option is unavailable for hashed indexes.
```

Comment: you might have given unique validation in the schema.

Comment: I don't know, my database is on another server in docker

Comment: I am looking at : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options

Comment: That's the issue you can see the error message `duplicate key error collection`

Comment: How can I create a collection without a unique validation in the schema ?

Comment: while creating schema don't give unique field true.

Comment: I didn't give any schema

Comment: There is a unique index existing in the collection. What do you have from running `print(collection.list_indexes())`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Peba's answer, you can use the `.copy()` method of python dictionary to avoid the mutation of the document itself.

```
document = {"auteur" : "romain",
            "text" : "premier post",
            "tag" : "test2",
            "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
collection.insert_one(document.copy())
collection.insert_one(document.copy())
```

This way, each `insert_one` call get's a shallow copy of the `document` and at the same time keeps your code more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a document implicitly generates an `_id`.
So after inserting the document it will mutate to

```
document = {"_id" : ObjectId('random_id_here'),
            "auteur" : "romain",
            "text" : "premier post",
            "tag" : "test2",
            "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
```

Trying to insert said document again will result in an error due to the duplicated `_id`.

You can create a new document with the same values and insert it.

```
document = {"auteur" : "romain",
            "text" : "premier post",
            "tag" : "test2",
            "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
collection.insert_one(document)

document = {"auteur" : "romain",
            "text" : "premier post",
            "tag" : "test2",
            "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
collection.insert_one(document)
```

Comment: that's strange. And the error disapear with the "save" method, which I use now (but is deprecated)

Comment: @romainjouin The save method is doing an upsert if an `_id`is already present in the document, so it's replacing the existing document instead of creating a new one. You can find more at [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save). I advise to not use it tho, and go for the non deprecated alternatives `insert_one()` or `replace_one()` instead.